# Angularjs ui-router resolves called twice

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This has been driving me crazy for the last couple of hours and I can't find a solution still...

Basically I'm changing the state to `404` when a resolve returns an http 404 status code. I'm changing the state in `$stateChangeError` event. It all works fine, except after the state is changed to `404` it starts another state change back to the original one thus resolving twice. The state itself remains on `404`, so after all, it works, but it still makes additional `$http` requests that are not needed. However, it only works like this if I use `$state.go('404', null, { location: false })` OR if the `404` state doesn't have an URL defined at all.

If I have an url defined for the `404` state (`/404`), then everything works just fine.

Here are 2 pens, demonstrating the issue:

The failing one: http://codepen.io/cprfnaporf/pen/RaqmQN (debug mode, check console: http://s.codepen.io/cprfnaporf/debug/RaqmQN/)

The working one: http://codepen.io/cprfnaporf/pen/MyzdVQ (debug mode, check console: http://s.codepen.io/cprfnaporf/debug/MyzdVQ/)

Any idea how to fix this issue? I'm out of ideas really.

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify your exact desired functionality.  Do you want to change to 404 state without showing a new view?  Just not sure what your end goal is.

Comment: I want to change the state to 404 without changing the url. That works, but as you can see in the console the resolves run twice in that case (for some reason it tries to load the state with the resolves again).

Comment: Which `resolve` is fired twice ?

Comment: The one for state `base` and the one for state `base.profile`. You can see in the log (http://s.codepen.io/cprfnaporf/debug/RaqmQN/).

Comment: I did a comparaison of logs and haven't seen anything difference. I just tried to debug but can't see which state is fired back when the `404` state is loaded...

Comment: @Zakaria: Check this image then, it's definitely happening: http://i.imgur.com/5BdlJdo.png

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem, the resolve from $stateProvider is called twice when using $state.go('module_state_name`)

Answer (score 4):

For me, you've already found the solution.
Indeed, as stated in your code :

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/profile/x/details');
```

The default url is `/profile/x/details`. When the `ui-router` sees
that url, it will try to load the states hierarchy : `base`, `base.profile` et `base.profile.details`. As you said, the last won't be loaded since you catch a 404 error and redirect the request elsewhere.

The problem is that you are still located at `/profile/x/details`. So in the `stateChangeError`, when you did the `$state.go('404', null, { location: false });`,  `ui-router` will check for the url.

Since it isn't set in the `404`, he will take the one he has : `/profile/x/details`.
And this is why he resolve the same states hierarchy : `base`, `base.profile` et `base.profile.details`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand all this, but the problem still remains. How can I avoid the additional resolves? Just leaving them there feels really ugly for me, but I don't want to update the url as that would be a bad UX as well in my opinion.

Comment: @Andrew I really understand your problem. But, I think that the main issue is with the app design and more specifically the states hierarchy.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that's all fine. See my last comment on **BatteryAcid**'s answer! Thank you for your effort though!

Answer (score 4):

@Andrew I guess I'm not sure exactly what your goals are but it seems like you're fighting the way ui-router works.

@Zakaria does a good job summarizing the issues.

Maybe take a step back and see if it really makes sense to keep a user on a dead page or partially dead page.   If you are trying to handle a failed resolve, then maybe catch that 404 (or failed request) and return a default resolve instead of moving to a new error state. By keeping your `when` statement at `$urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/profile/x/details');` you are only going to run into problems the way it's currently designed

Comment: Well, that's the thing. It's not because of the `.when` statement. That's only there to illustrate the problem fast. The thing is, it happens on the initial page load even if it's not redirected, but I couldn't find a way to illustrate like that in codepen. So if you open `/profile/x/details` directly the problem still occurs. In the real application I'm not using this `when` statement.

Comment: Ok. What about handling the resolve more gracefully?

Comment: What do you propose? I really can't think of a way that would be easy to use app-wise. Basically I just want to show a real simple 404 page when *any* API call returns 404, without changing the url. Should I actually return some custom type of data and wrap every single API call? I'll be honest, that seems to me a huge overkill for such a small task. I'm not trying to nitpick here, I hope you understand. :)

Comment: @Andrew I pulled this code into a local Play Framework server, removed the `when` statement, and navigated to `/profile/x/details/` and do not see details loaded twice.  Unless I'm missing something, I think using the `when` to illustrate the problem is causing issues.  Maybe we can tackle it another way?

Comment: Have you actually tried to load `/profile/x/details` initially? The problem only occurs on the initial page load, not when you navigate to it with `ui-sref` or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, I navigate straight to it.

Comment: That's weird, it's happening on my local site without `when`. Is there a way to upload it somewhere so I can check it?

Comment: You can pull this code, Note it's on an older version of Play, 2.3 I think, but it  should work if you download the latest.  I did make some changes in the routing configs like nested the error state, etc.  Take a look: https://github.com/BatteryAcid/ui-router-issue/tree/ui-router-issue

Comment: Okay, I've just tried this out and it works fine. I found out though, the issue is definitely coming back when I add `ct.ui.router.extras` as a dependency. I guess I'll have to poke around there. Thank you!

Comment: Narrowed it down even more. The problem is somewhere in the `ct.ui.router.extras.future` module. Thankfully I don't need that one, now I'm explicitly importing the ones I need and the problem went away immediately.

Comment: Good to hear, let me know if you need any help